# Angular configuration for dev/prod

Tags: angular, angular-builder, angular-config

I use Auth0 service which provides me two client_id's - for development and for production. However, this has to be built-in source code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  // Create an observable of Auth0 instance of client
  auth0Client$ = (from(
    createAuth0Client({
      domain: 'xxxxx',
      client_id: 'Mx9x.........',
      redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/authorize`,
      audience: 'xxxx'
    })
  ) as Observable<Auth0Client>).pipe(
    shareReplay(1), // Every subscription receives the same shared value
    catchError(err => throwError(err))
  );
```

I would love to use one during local development and another for production built. Is this doable?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`?

Comment: Thanks Bunyamin & Ahmed, your solution works. Shame on me, should have know myself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use `environment.ts` for development config/keys and  `environment.prod.ts` for production config/keys , where during build when using `ng build --prod` angular replace `environment.ts` with `environment-prod.ts`